# How to register a lookup in django?

Tags: python, django, search

I'm trying to use `__lower` to search with django, but when I run the view of it, it throws this error:

`Unsupported lookup 'lower' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.`

So, I searched for possible solutions, and found that I need to register that lookup, but I can't figure out where should I do it.

The code is:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

CharField.register_lookup(Lower)
```

I tried running it into `myapp.apps`, or even `manage.py shell`, but got no success.

Into django docs, I was not able to find any clear mention of it.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you write that code?

Comment: The `__lower` call was inside a view, and the register one I don't know exactly where to run it, but tried into the `manage.py shell` and inside the app `apps.py` file (outside any class or methods).

Comment: The `Lower` is a DB function and can be used as part of the query to convert a field/value. You will need to create a custom `Lookup` if you want to do this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-lookups/

Comment: @IainShelvington: The MRO of `Lower` contains the [`RegisterLookupMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8593e162c9cb63a6c0b06daf045bc1c21eb4d7c1/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L167), which is sufficient to register it as a lookup. For example you can register it in the Django shell and then use it with `Foo.objects.filter(title__lower='a')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *run* the `register_lookup` code. You can for example do this in the `def read()` of the `AppConfig`, so:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'
    verbose_name = 'App name'

    def ready(self):
        from django.db.models import CharField
        from django.db.models.functions import Lower

        CharField.register_lookup(Lower)
```

You then should make the *`MyAppConfig`* as the standard `AppConfig`, you do this in the `__init__.py` of the app:

```
# app_name/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Note however that you should *not* use `Lower` or `Upper` to make case-insensitive comparisons: some characters have no lowercase equivalent and vice versa. You make case insenstive comparisons with the [**`__iexact`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact).